# Displaying content based off of select tag option

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get a dropdown search selector to open content based off of a selection, whether it is through the search function or selection from drop down, however I can't get the selector to work properly.

I've decided to use select2 instead of a custom built dropdown search selector. With this, I had to use the reference the direct links to the CSS and JS files. For some reason referencing the files locally isn't working. The new issue I'm having is when I select one option, both options are displayed. Where am I messing this up at?

See below code for what I have already attempted:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="../CSS/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../JS/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../JS/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<style>
@font-face {
 font-family:"Poppins";
 src: url("../Font/Poppins/Poppins-Regular.woff") format('woff');
 font-weight: 600;
}
html {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif; 
 overflow: hidden;
}

.video_container {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 65vw;
 height: 80vh;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 1%;
}

.select_div_container {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 30vw;
 height: 80vh;
 float: left;
 postion: fixed;
}

.select_div_desc {
 width: 75%;
 height: 40vh;
 overflow: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

.video_iframe, .video_span {
 display: none;  
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
 .select_div_container {width: 100%; height: 45vh;}
 .select_div_desc {width: 100%; height: 60%;}
 .video_container {width: 100%; height: 40vh;}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1400px) {

}

@media screen and (min-width: 1401px) and (max-width: 1920px) {

}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.dropped').select2();
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".dropped").change(function() {
         var val= $(this).find("option a").attr('name');
         $(".video_iframe").show("slow");
         $(".video_span").show("slow");
         $("#"+val).show("slow");
         $("."+val).show("slow");
     });    
 });   
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="select_div_container"><select class="dropped" style="width: 100%;" > <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select a Training Video</option><optgroup label="DROPPER"><option><a name="video_01">VIDEO#1</a></option><option><a name="video_02">VIDEO #2</a></option></optgroup></select><br><br><br><br><div class="select_div_desc"><span class="video_span" class="video_01">VIDEO #1 DESCRIPTION</span><span class="video_span" class="video_02">VIDEO #2 DESCRIPTION</span></div></div>

<div class="video_container">
 <iframe class="video_iframe" id="video_01"  src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/d9zEho-gQd9zE" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 <iframe class="video_iframe" id="video_02" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/_9zEhpAYoYo-g" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The <A> tag is not valid within an <OPTION> tag. The only content allowed between <OPTION> tags is text. [HTML Elements Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) That's why your selector isn't finding that element.

Instead of storing the video ID in the <A> tag in the **name** attribute, simply set the **value** of each <OPTION> to that ID. Then the **val()** of the entire <SELECT> becomes that video ID when changed. Here's my version of that section of markup:

```
<div class="select_div_container">
<select class="dropped" style="width: 100%;">
    <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Select a Training Video</option>
    <optgroup label="DROPPER">
        <option value="video_01">VIDEO #1</option>
        <option value="video_02">VIDEO #2</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
<br/><br/><br/><br/>
<div class="select_div_desc">
    <span class="video_span video_01">VIDEO #1 DESCRIPTION</span>
    <span class="video_span video_02">VIDEO #2 DESCRIPTION</span>
</div>
</div>
```

And here's how I modified the JavaScript:

```
 $(".dropped").change(function()
 {
     var videoId = $(this).val();
     $(".video_iframe, .video_span").hide();
     $("#" + videoId + ", ." + videoId).show("slow");
 });
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: another thing. Do you see why my css and js, referenced locally isn't working? Yet the script and css called remotely does?

Comment: I'd use the script debugger feature on your browser (F12 on Internet Explorer) and see if those local references are being loaded correctly.

Comment: it say's "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined, at select2.min.js:2"

Comment: You may have to include jquery above the other two.

Comment: thank you! I had to put the library at the top before the select2 js file. Which kind of makes sense.

Comment: another thing I can't seem to figure out is when switching in between the select options, the original youtube video still plays unless you physical pause it. Is there anyway to stop the video playback with javascript?